# A question about normal subgroups and index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. $|H|=11$ and $[G:H]=24$. Let there be $x \in G$ and $x^{11}=e$. Show $x \in H$.

Would like hints etc' on how to solve this. Is proving that $x \in H$ basically means showing that $Hx=H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Look at the coset of $\;xH\;$ of $\;x\;$in the quotient group, and use (or prove, if you haven't yet seen this):

$$ord(xH)\mid ord(x)\;,\;\;\text{and also}\;\;ord(xH)\mid ord\left(G/H\right)=[G:H]$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $H\lhd G$, we can consider the canonical homomorphism $G\to G/H$. Under this, $x$ is mapped to an element of $G/H$ of order dividing $11$ (i.e. $1$ or $11$). Since $G/H$ has order $12$, there is no element of order $11$, hence $x$ maps to an element of order $1$, i.e. the neutral element of $G/H$. This is equivalent to $x\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $|G| = 11\times 24$, so $H$ is the 11-Sylow subgroup of $G$. Since $H$ is normal, it is the unique 11-Sylow subgroup. But that means $H$ must contain all elements of order 11 (or 1)

Comment: Hmmm...the basic nature of the question could indicate the OP hasn't yet covered Sylow theorems...